# Как перевести первый символ в верхний регистр

Tags: php

Есть строка, нужно первый символ перевести в верхний регистр...

```
 ucfirst();
```

с кириллицей не работает....

Comment: У меня прекрасно работает как с юникодом так и с кириллицей...

Попробуйте прописать локаль

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, array('ru_RU.CP1251', "ru_RU","ru","rus_RUS"));

Comment: @avp а поиск на форуме для кого?

Comment: @Shrek, а Вы уверены, что он адекватно работает ?

Я попробовал здесь с этим вопросом, конкретно ввел *перевести символ верхний регистр php*. И ничего, ответов 0 !

-

Кстати, почитал "справку", а там никаких конкретных указаний о том, **как искать**. Только совет пользоваться поиском.

Comment: Ребят, вот чесно.Вы в гугле тоже вводите в строку поиска только один вариант и ждете что он покажет вам все?

Можно поискать по одному слову, вероятность нахождения вопроса возрастает, я вот поражаюсь, вы что думаете что здесь прям такой же поиск как яндекс или гугл? 


поищите [букву][1] на форуме, третья ссылка сразу попадаете на нужный вопрос.

Не мне вас учить как пользоваться поиском, но складывается ощущение, что не только те кто задает вопросы,а еще и те кто отвечает не умеют "БОНАЛЬНО" пользоваться поиском


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83&t=question

Comment: @avp  [твой же поисковый запрос][1] без первых слов, прям в точку выводит ответ.

Из этого просто вывод один.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80+php&t=question

Comment: Да, @Shrek, вывод здесь один - поиск здесь слабо селективен, работает видимо (в основном) по .AND. Если задать мало слов (а может и не один раз) и прочесть все ответы ..... (ну в конкретном случае может и повезет).

-

На самом деле поиск надо серьезно улучшать (а как минимум опубликовать хорошую инструкцию по нему).

Comment: Ну вот @avp собственно я это и не стал писать. Работает он точно по AND при написании вопроса, нужно некоторые слова при автопоиске заменять на другие, но писать интуитивный поиск вряд ли кто тут будет. А вот инструкцию по поиску - это да!

Comment: А для начала как-то отметить (например иконкой) поле ввода поискового запроса на странице. 

Подозреваю, что не все находят это поле.

Answer (score 3):

На [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) предлагаются два решения:

```
<?php 
function ucfirst_utf8($stri){ 
 if($stri{0}>="\xc3") 
     return (($stri{1}>="\xa0")? 
     ($stri{0}.chr(ord($stri{1})-32)): 
     ($stri{0}.$stri{1})).substr($stri,2); 
 else return ucfirst($stri); 
} 
?>
```

и

```
<?php 
function mb_ucasefirst($str){ 
    $str[0] = mb_strtoupper($str[0]); 
    return $str; 
} 
?>
```

Попробуйте, какое из них вам подойдет.

Comment: Странно, ни тот ту другой вариант не работают... как были маленькими так и остались...

Comment: У меня первый вариант сработал. Кодировка файла utf без BOM?